# Ask for permissions with facebook login button

Tags: android, facebook, widget

I have the facebook login widget, defined in my xml as:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/login_facebook"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        fb:login_text="@string/login_facebook"
        fb:logout_text="@string/login_facebook"
        android:contentDescription="@string/login_facebook"
        android:background="@drawable/login_activity_facebook_unpressed"
        />
```

With no extra code whatsoever used then clicking on this button will take the user to the permissions page for facebook and ask for "public profile" information. I want to also ask for the email permission. How can I override the default click behaviour of the facebook widget so that it asks for email permissions when it is clicked on?

I've tried inserting extra code, but it always invokes the default "public profile" logic before reaching anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use method setReadPermissions() of LoginButton

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);


loginButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
```

Comment: I tried to do this in the past without success. However, I realised after reading your answer that I was putting in this code in the wrong place: onActivityCreated when it needed to be in onCreateView - and this solved the problem.